# Snowflake Python Worksheet - main handler with additional arguments

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The goal is to develop and Deploy Snowpark code inside Python Worksheet code that could take user input.

If we try to provide additional user-defined arguments we get:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session, param):
    df = session.table('snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem').limit(param)
    return df
```

> **Handler has more arguments than expected.** Function signature must have exactly one  argument:
>
> ```
>    def main(session: snowpark.Session):
> ```

If we try to Deploy the code to a stored procedure:

[image]

[image]

> Stored procedure my_proc could not be created.
> failed running query:  **Python function is defined with 2 arguments (including session), but stored procedure definition contains 0 arguments. Python function arguments are expected to be session and stored procedure defined arguments in function MY_PROC with handler main**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to workaround this limitation is to develop the code using Python Worksheet using local variables and leaving `main(session: snowpark.Session)` signature unchanged:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    param = 1
    df = session.table('snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem').limit(param)
    return df
```

When the code is ready and Deploy window is visible, "Open with Worksheets" should be chosen:

[image]

It will open SQL Worksheet:

[image]

```
create procedure my_proc()
    returns Table()
    language python
    runtime_version = 3.8
    packages =('snowflake-snowpark-python')
    handler = 'main'
    as 'import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    param = 1
    df = session.table(''snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem'').limit(param)
    return df';
```

Then necessary code adjustments could be made including:

1. removing local Python variables
2. changing `main` function signature
3. changing SQL stored procedure signature

After:

```
create procedure my_proc(param INT)
    returns Table()
    language python
    runtime_version = 3.8
    packages =('snowflake-snowpark-python')
    handler = 'main'
    as 'import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session, param:int):
    df = session.table(''snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem'').limit(param)
    return df';
```

[image]

Now it is possible to use parametrized stored procedure:

[image]